# Declaring "using Dates" in my module, but have to state "using Dates" again in my script

Tags: julia

v0.3-

I have a module as such

```
module MyModule

using Dates
.
.
.
end # module
```

Now when I go to write a script to use `MyModule` it tells me DateTime is not defined.

```
using MyModule

dt = DateTime("20140101", "yyyymmdd")
```

But it works if I have:

```
using MyModule
using Dates

dt = DateTime("20140101", "yyyymmdd")
```

I would've thought that if it is being made visible via `MyModule` that I wouldn't have to 'pull it in' again?

Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the best resource for understanding module usage in Julia: http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/modules/#summary-of-module-usage

In short, saying `using Dates` in your module, brings the `Dates` module exports into your *module's* namespace, but not the *global* namespace. Meaning if you still want to access `Dates` exports from the top level, you'll have to call `using Dates` again.

Also checkout the [Reexport.jl](https://github.com/simonster/Reexport.jl) package aimed at making this easier.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, I don';t see that info anywhere in the documentation (I've re-read it just now as I have read it before as well). The closest I could find to "usage" of `using` was: *"The statement using Lib means that a module called Lib will be available for resolving names as needed"*, hence why I thought it should've been avaiable.

Comment: Anything you find confusing about the documentation should probably be fixed. The easiest approach is to edit the file directly in GitHub (use the little pencil icon).